# Scopes without parameters with a ransack form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I want to have a checkbox in my ransack form that selects to use a class method or scope. The scope has no parameters.

```
#model
def self.new
    where.not(sku: retailer.products.pluck(:sku).uniq)
end

# view
<%= f.check_box :new, class: 'mr-sm-2 ' %>
```

But i get error:

"undefined method `new'"

How do I add a form element to the search_form to select to use the scope?

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist scopes. In your model create a class method named `ransackable_scopes` that returns an array of scope names that you want to whitelist:

```
def self.ransackable_scopes(auth_object = nil)
  [:new]
end
```

As a side note I would recommend not naming your scope `new`. While it might technically work in this context, `new` is how you call a class constructor in Ruby. So defining a method named `new` in your modal class might cause problems elsewhere in your application.